# How do I call a specific protocol using Twisted

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

So I'm trying to make a very basic MUD and I may be going about it the wrong way but I just need some coding help. This code includes twisted that I've tweaked for testing means to try and understand it, however I have run into a road block.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time


class Chat(LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None
        self.health = 10
        self.state = "GETNAME"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.users.has_key(self.name):
            print self.name, "has disconnected"
            del self.users[self.name]

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:
            if self.state == "CHAT":
                self.handle_CHAT(line)
            else:
                if self.state == "ATTACK":
                    self.handle_ATTACK(line)

    def handle_GETNAME(self, name):
        if self.users.has_key(name):
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
        print name, "has connected"
        self.sendLine("You currently have %s health..." % (self.health))
        self.name = name
        self.users[name] = self
        for name, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol != self:
                message = "%s has joined" % (self.name,)
                protocol.sendLine(message)
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self, message):
        if(message[0:3] == 'say'):
            try:
                message = message[4:]
                message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
                print message
                for name, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
                    if protocol != self:
                        protocol.sendLine(message)
            except:
                print "Chat failed"
        if(message == 'test'):
            try:
                self.handle_TEST()
            except:
                print "Testing Failed"
        if(message == 'attack'):
            try:
                self.handle_ATTACKINIT()
            except:
                print "Attack Failed"

    def handle_ATTACKINIT(self):
        self.sendLine("Who are you attacking?")
        self.state = "ATTACK"

    def handle_ATTACK(self, target):
        for target, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol == target:
                target.sendLine("You have been attacked!")
                protocol.sendLine("You now have %s health remaining..." % (self.health,))
            else:
                self.sendLine("No target with that name")

    def handle_TEST(self):
        print name, "is Testing"
        self.sendLine("This is a test")
        self.state = "CHAT"


class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}  # maps user names to Chat instances

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)


reactor.listenTCP(8123, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

The main function I need help with is this function...

```
    def handle_ATTACK(self, target):
        for target, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol == target:
                target.sendLine("You have been attacked!")
                protocol.sendLine("You now have %s health remaining..." % (self.health,))
            else:
                self.sendLine("No target with that name")
```

I need to find the 'target's' protocol to send it a message and deal damage to it.

I figured out that it is saving the Name/Protocol match in the list self.users, and I'm guessing I look for "target's" protocol in the set self.users.iteritems() but I'm having trouble accessing a specific protocol and utilizing it.

Any help for the beginning novice that is messing with twisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've shadowed your `target` parameter with a loop variable:

```
def handle_ATTACK(self, target):
    for target, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
        if protocol == target:
```

Before the loop starts, `target` identifies the user to attack.  After the loop starts, it identifies one of the keys in the `self.users` dictionary.

Then, you compare that key to `protocol` - which is one of the *values* of the `self.users` dictionary.  This probably isn't what you intended.

Try comparing the `target` parameter to keys from `self.users` and then using the corresponding value as the protocol to use to send data.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna go ahead and check this out now, and get back. Thanks for the response